# Hi I want to know what is the appropriate process of converting Amplitude to dB . Through Android device

Tags: android

I want to know what is the appropriate process of converting Amplitude to dB. I am using double as below

```
db = (20 * Math.log10(mediaRecorder.getMaximimAmplitude));
```

But there are suggestions to use double as below

```
db = (20 * Math.log10(x2 / REFERENCE));
```

I dont know what reference is to use in which scenerio

Answer (score 0):

The decibel is a much misused unit. It is defined as the 10 log (P1/P2) where P1 is the measured power, and P2 is the reference power. That is, it is always relative to some reference power. A common reference power is one milliwatt, and this is the definition of dBm. 0dBm is one milliwatt; +30dbm is one watt. Don't be misled by the oft-quoted "0dBm = one milliwatt in 600 ohms". This is an artifact of when voltage measuring devices were used to display dBm. Because they were voltage measuring rather than power measuring, an impedance at which they read correctly needed to be specified, and it was nearly always 600 ohms.

Over the years dB usage has been stretched to cover situations where having a logarithmic unit is really useful. For instance the voltage gain of an amplifier may be quoted in dB, using the formula 20log(Vout/Vin). In this situation, the input and output impedances (and hence powers) are often vastly different, so the usage is technically wrong. In practice it is a convenient unit to work with, and has been given some legitimacy by labeling it dBv.

The first formula you are using will return dB referenced to 1 volt in whatever impedance your circuit exhibits. This is fine, but it won't be dBm. Often this does not matter, as you just need to graph gain in dB against an arbitrary reference.If you need it to be dBm just find the circuit impedance and use Ohms law to work out what voltage represents one milliwatt in that impedance.

The second formula is a bit strange. What is **x2**? I would expect the formula to be 20log(Vmeasured/Vreference).

Comment: Thanks great discription. I have one more doubt .Is the microphone output or "amplitude" that you use for Android devices specified at 0 - 1V?  If not, do you know what it is?